# why javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor's static filed is null?

Tags: java

I use `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` to process my annotation,and set the static field,but I found the static field's value is null when I use it at runtime, why? 
for example:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"com.qunar.hotel.config.annotation.HConfig"})
public class HConfigAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    public static volatile List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList();
    public static String str =  null;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        str="wo lai dao le zhe li";
        list.add("test");
```

Comment: which field is null?

Comment: static fields, list and str